# Cannot submit HTML form using PHP on iPad

Tags: php, html, forms, ipad, submit

Recently I got this problem that I cannot solve. My HTML form cannot be submitted by using iPad, but the same form CAN be submitted from my laptop (windows machine). Please check this out:

http://www.gomap.ch/admin/pages/test.php - this is submitted correctly
http://ipadpreview.com/previewer?url=www.gomap.ch/admin/pages/test.php - this is not submitted.

This is a very simple form, and code goes like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    if($_POST['mirko']){
        echo 'hello, Mirko';
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="mirko"/>
</form>
```

Any help, please??
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried writing valid HTML?

Comment: Have you tried it on a real iPad?

Comment: The "simulator" you are using drops the `action` property from the form element. I'm sure it works on a real iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using valid html.Replace your code with this  and have u  tried  on real ipad.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if($_POST['mirko']){
    echo 'hello, Mirko';
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="mirko"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the name of the form which holds the php code into the action. In this case it would be the same form you're on. Follow what I did below with nameOfFile.php being the name of the file you posted.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if($_POST['mirko']){
    echo 'hello, Mirko';
}
?>

<form action="nameOfFile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="mirko"/>
</form>
```